# Trigger event on click outside page

Tags: javascript, events

Is possible trigger an event if user click outside page? More specifically, in the browser title bar or tab bar?

Try this my [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LnFGK/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="menu">Click here</div>
    <div id="show">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery('div#menu').on('click', function(ev) {
    jQuery('div#show').addClass('visible').css({
        top: ev.clientY,
        left: ev.clientX
    });

    return false;
});

jQuery(document).click(function() {
    jQuery('div#show').removeClass('visible');
});

jQuery(window).blur(function() {
    jQuery(document).click();
});
```

**TESTS**

First you click in "Click here" button. So...

1. Try to click in some document part: Ok
2. Try to click in some page part or unfocus browser window: Ok
3. Try to click in some other opened tab in your browser: Ok
4. Try to click in browser title bar or tab title: Fail

**SO...**

It's possible I solve this problem?

**TEST RESULTS**

- **Chrome**: fail on last;
- **Firefox**: fail on last;
- **IE10**: fail on last;
- **Opera**: fail on last;

Comment: Your jsFiddle works in Chrome 48. Clicking the current tab doesn't close the menu but clicking another tab in Chrome or clicking outside of the Chrome window does close the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you this, but this isn't possible.

Reason? Well essentially, clicking the title bar/tab bar of a window doesn't actually make an element lose focus.

Try this example here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onblur

You'll notice that clicking the title bar/tab bar doesn't make the textbox lose focus at all, which is the root of the issue.

I don't think this is a big deal for your project though. As far as the user's concerned, it'll look great as it currently is.